# Odoo Inheritance : AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'action_send_email'

Tags: inheritance, odoo-16

I am trying something simple : Edit helpdesk ticket stage, when we click on "repair" on the repair view of the concerned ticket.

What I did :

1- Inside a custom module, add the depend on repair in the manifest file

```
'depends':['base', 'repair', 'helpdesk', 'stock'],
```

2- inside my models folder, create a repair.py as

```
from odoo import api, fields, models
class Repair(models.Model):
    _inherit = "repair.order"
    def action_send_mail(self):
        res = super().action_send_email()

        #mark ticket "waiting for customer validation"
        mystuff

        return res
```

And I get the error

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'action_send_email'

thank you for your help

I tried many things

- check on google
- verify every indent and spaces
- try to give the class name inside super call - super(Repair)

I am totally stucked ...

What I am trying to inheritate is ***repair.py in src/odoo/addons/repair/models/repair.py***

(where of course we have the class Repair named repair.order, and the method def action_send_mail(self))

**EDIT:**
News : I can call super().action_repair_confirm with success
But no way to have super().action_send_mail, it is still saying no attribute 'action_send_email'

So I add log into the original action_send_

wow, writing this comment I am seeing the problem ...

action_send_mail vs action_send_**e**mail

god ...

over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action_send_mail vs action_send_**e**mail

Wasted so much time for that ...